# Order mysql query by repeating sequence of ID

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a mysql table as follows:

```
| key | storeID | product |
---------------------------
|  1  | 12      | Apple   |
|  2  | 12      | Banana  |
|  3  |  9      | Orange  |
|  4  |  9      | Durian  |
|  5  | 15      | Melon   |
|  6  | 15      | Berry   |
|  7  |  9      | Grape   |
|  8  | 15      | Tomato  |
|  9  | 12      | Plum    |
```

Is there a way to order the query such that storeID is output in a repeating sequence as follows?

**Desired Output:**

```
| key | storeID | product |
---------------------------
|  3  |  9      | Orange  |
|  1  | 12      | Apple   |
|  5  | 15      | Melon   |
|  4  |  9      | Durian  |
|  2  | 12      | Banana  |
|  6  | 15      | Berry   |  etc
```

I have searched and found some vague responses which included cross joins with group by's but ended up losing the corresponding product field.

Open to php solution if necessary.

Many thanks for any pointers

**EDIT**
As per advice from @strawberry below and in response to the first responded answer, here is the code for the tables with added rows

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (`key` INTEGER, `storeID` INTEGER,`product` VARCHAR(6));
    
    INSERT INTO inventory
    (key, storeID, product)
    VALUES
    (1, 12, 'Apple'),
    (2, 12, 'Banana'),
    (3, 9, 'Orange'),
    (4, 9, 'Durian'),
    (5, 15, 'Melon'),
    (6, 15, 'Berry'),
    (7, 9, 'Grape'),
    (8, 15, 'Tomato'),
    (9, 12, 'Plum');
```

Comment: @Strawberry - Is this edit what you had in mind?

Comment: Yep. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can do it with ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM inventory
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY storeID ORDER BY `key`),
         storeID
```

For previous versions of MySql you can use a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM inventory t1
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inventory t2 WHERE t2.storeID = t1.storeID AND t2.`key` < t1.`key`),
         t1.storeID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=71cf2c706f26032cdf89a12dbc9c0bd2).
Results:

| key | storeID | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 9 | Orange |
| 1 | 12 | Apple |
| 5 | 15 | Melon |
| 4 | 9 | Durian |
| 2 | 12 | Banana |
| 6 | 15 | Berry |
| 7 | 9 | Grape |
| 9 | 12 | Plum |
| 8 | 15 | Tomato |

Comment: thanks for the speedy and luscious reply. My version of sql < 8.0 so I went with the second option which did answer the original question, however, when I inserted it into a larger table with more storeID's, the order sequence of the storeID's was not being strictly adhered to while the 'key' field order was taking priority. Any ideas??

Comment: @midget I can only have ideas about the requirement and the sample data as you posted them in your question. If you have a different requirement you can post a new question.

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option for older versions, but it may not scale particularly well...

```
select x.*
  from inventory x
  join inventory y
    on y.storeid = x.storeid
   and y.id <= x.id
 group
    by x.id
 order
    by count(*)
     , storeid
```

I've called the identity column 'id' instead of 'key', because reserved words make poor table/column identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does solve the problem at hand. Not sure why the downvote or if it scales well also but I accepted the first response from @forpas as it came in first and works. I appreciate the contributions regarding the formation of questions and tip on column names.  EDIT: - I do see now that the 'id' field has not shifted accordingly!

Comment: More mysterious is the lack of an upvote (and in point of fact, the accepted part of that answer came 6 hours after mine ;-)  ) That said, I suspect forpas's solution is faster.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see your's right away. Upvoted now. Not sure why the id field didn't order correctly when i tried last time but whaterver the case was, your solution works fine too